# Spring Cloud Config Client is not fetching automatically configuration from server

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I am implementing Spring Cloud config, but the clients are not fetching the config automatically...
When I start up my client gets the data from the server properly, but never retrieves it again.

This is my CloudConfig Server.

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableConfigServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class CloudConfigApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CloudConfigApplication.class, args);
    }
```

}

aplication.yml

```
eureka:
    client:
        serviceUrl:
            defaultZone: http://localhost:9091/eureka
server:
    port: 8888
spring:
    application:
        name: config-server
    cloud:
        config:
            server:
                bootstrap: true
                health:
                    enabled: true
                native:
                    searchLocations: file:${user.dir}/src/main/resources/configs/
    profiles:
        active: native
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>CloudConfig</groupId>
    <artifactId>CloudConfig</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>CloudConfig</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- 3a) Dependency for spring-cloud-config-Server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- 3b) Dependency for testing boot projects -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>



    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

/src/main/resources/config/CloudConfigClient.yaml

```
test: aaaaa
test2: 1111
```

SpringCloud Client

```
@EnableScheduling
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration

public class CloudConfigClient {

    
     @Value("${test}")
     private String myProperty;
     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CloudConfigClient.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay =1000)
    public void printProperty() {
        System.out.println("Value of property \"myProperty\": " + myProperty);
    }
}
```

bootstrap.yaml

```
eureka:
    client:
        serviceUrl:
            defaultZone: http://localhost:9091/eureka
server:
    port: 7004

    datasource:
        driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    application:
        name: CloudConfigClient
    cloud:
        config:
             uri: http://localhost:8888
             fail-fast: true
             max-attempts: 20
             max-interval: 15000
             initial-interval: 10000
```

Pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>


<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

This is the ouput log:

```
2020-11-20 23:33:12.747  INFO 16764 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
2020-11-20 23:33:13.510  INFO 16764 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Located environment: name=CloudConfigClient, profiles=[default], label=null, version=null, state=null
2020-11-20 23:33:13.510  INFO 16764 --- [  restartedMain] b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source: CompositePropertySource {name='configService', propertySources=[MapPropertySource {name='file:D:/CloudConfig/src/main/resources/configs/CloudConfigClient.yaml'}]}

...
...
Value of property "myProperty": aaaaa
Value of property "myProperty": aaaaa
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want your config to be refresh you have to use **@RefreshScope** [spring doc](https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/) the config won't get update by magic himself because you call @Scheduled.

But base on how you fetch the value in Configuration component they might be limitation and **@RefreshScope** will not work [refreshscope](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-commons/2.1.2.RELEASE/multi/multi__spring_cloud_context_application_context_services.html#refresh-scope)

I suggest create a bean a **@ConfigurationProperties** and annotate with **@RefreshScope** when you hit from actuator endpoint **/refresh** everything should update or maybe combination of **@Schedule** you might achieved what you want

Comment: I thought that the CloudConfig Client are able to retrieve automatically or maybe need some config in application.properties... but if this is not the behaviour... I can implement in my CloudConfig Server the feature to invoke the micro service /actuator/refresh when a config file changed.